# I am getting the following errors in wso2esb 4.7.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I used previous version of wso2 esb and now I've shifted all my
services to latest version of wso2 esb 4.7.0, but still I am getting same error.

If clients sending parallel requests that time its giving some ERRORS and
Warnings like this:

```
SourceHandler I/O error (Probably the connection was closed by the remote party):Broken pipe
 WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-2240
18,799]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out while writing the response: http-incoming-2156
[2013-08-14 17:10:19,801]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out while writing the response: http-incoming-2161
[2013-08-14 17:10:19,801]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out while writing the response: http-incoming-2171
[2013-08-14 17:10:19,802]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out while writing the response: http-incoming-2162
[2013-08-14 17:10:19,802]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out while writing the response: http-incoming-2178
[2013-08-14 17:10:19,802]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out while writing the response: http-incoming-2159
[2013-08-14 17:10:19,802]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out while writing the response: http-incoming-2173
[2013-08-14 17:10:19,803]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out while writing the response: http-incoming-2179
[2013-08-14 17:10:19,803]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out while writing the response: http-incoming-2174
[2013-08-14 17:13:50,157]  INFO - LogMediator To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:b522b7bb-c01c-4b6c-a214-3cb00cb6c663, Direction: response, clientid = ...
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: What is the use case here?
Can you add the synapseConfig

Comment: but where can i find this file .is it any configure file modification or service level

Comment: Put the xml file in proxy service, which the requests are sent to.
Go to List proxy services and click on source view. Copy and paste the source here

Comment: which xml file your talking about..my request will come from mobile clients.In that case where i need Copy the xml file.will you please write the sample code for this.